# Spring amqp - message correlation in asynchronous request/response scenario

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, messaging, spring-amqp

At the moment I develop a small crawler/scraper application which is split into two parts. The first part (requestor) builds URLs based on some pattern and sends it to the consumer (secound part), which does the acutal scraping und returns the result. The result is then further processed and might be send to another queue and so on.

So I thought it would be a good idea to use messaging with the spring-amqp project and a RabbitMQ Messaging Service to queue all the requests. That way I can setup multiple consumers, which all listens to the request queue. Right now I use convertAndSend to make asynchronous requests from the requestor

```
@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate messagingTemplate;

public void doMessaging(String url){
    ...
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, url);

}
```

and receive the result in a MessageListener, which listens to a Response queue. So far everything works, but my problem is that the sending part and the receiving part of the Requestor is independent and i dont know how to make sure  that i got a response for every request message (like I could when using convertSendAndReceive).

So my question is: Are there any good patterns for this problem or do I have to cache all requests with some correlationId and manually check if a response arrives?

[image]

**Update:**

Basically I am looking for patterns in general because the asynchronicity of convertAndSend() as it is provided by spring-amqp is fine.

My Scenario in more detail: The component that I called "requestor" in the diagramm reads some configurable values from a database. Based on these information it creates an object, lets say a "crawl-run", that holds information about the crawling activities. After that "phase 1" starts, where the requestor builds URLs based on the configurable values and sends them to queue1. Queue1 consumer scrap the Webpage and send the response to response-queue1.

The requestor listens on response-queue1, takes the results and pushes new messages to request-queue2 ("Phase 2") etc...

My problem is: how can I know that for example all phases of a "crawl-run" are worked off/completed to store some meta-data about this run and close it?

One idea might be, to create a correlationId for every request message, store it in a map and remove the entry when a response with the same correlationId arrives, but I thought that might not be the beste practice. Are there any suggested solutions or patterns to deal with this asynchronous request response Scenario?

Comment: Are you looking for alternative patterns in general, or built-in components to the `spring-amqp` platform which handle correlating request and reply?

Comment: I updated my questions. Maybe it is a bit clearer now. Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a suitable answer? I am interested in how you resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The [Spring Integration Project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) has all the components you need.

The exact implementation will depend on your requirements - you can either use a barrier to suspend the calling thread until the reply is received, or an aggregator for completely async processing where the aggregator can send an error message if no reply is received, for example.

If you can provide more details about your exact requirements we can get you started.

If you don't want to use Spring Integration for some reason, you can use the template's `convertAndSend` variant that takes a `MessagePostProcessor` so you can set a correlation id.

You can use a `@RabbitListener` to receive the reply where the POJO method gets the converted payload and the correlation id header.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like the issue you have is a RabbitMQ issue; rather, it is a matter for how your application tracks long-running tasks.

From a conceptual standpoint, you need to keep track of the tasks status somewhere, since that is what you are interested in.  RabbitMQ will not allow you to view messages that are enqueued.  Therefore, you would need to have a separate component of your application keep track of the state of the various jobs that are out there.